# Twitter Bootstrap 3 Responsive menu not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've just started using Twitter Bootstrap 3.0, I've been reading the documentation and I'm trying to create a responsive navigation bar, my code is the same structure as the example in the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default) but it doesn't seem to be working for some reason.

Below is the HTML code I'm using, I'm just using the default CSS and Javascript files.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Efar Communication Services</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <!-- For screen readers and mobiles -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

    <a class="navbar-brand">Efar</a>
    <p class="navbar-text">Business Infrastructure Solutions</p>
  </div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Client Area</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
  </div> <!-- End of container -->
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That code is working fine here: http://bootply.com/80966 (be sure to click on the phone icon middle left to see). Is what is happening here not what you are expecting?

Comment: Yeh, thats what I want it to look like, but on my computer with the same code, when I click on the menu to show the links, nothing happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that where I had `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>`, it turns out that the site wasn't responding and so the page couldn't use jquery, which it needs to work. So I downloaded a local copy of jquery and changed it to `<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>`. Now it's working fine

Comment: You don't have to have a local copy for it to work. The reason your jQuery won't load is because you're not telling it which transfer protocol to use. You need to prefix your link to jQuery with `http` or `https` so that the browser knows what protocol to use to load the script. So, your new script src should be something like `src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"`.

Comment: Actually it does matter in some cases.

At my company I'm behind a TMG proxy and somehow, when connecting trough it, even if I have "http"://code.jquery.com, it doe NOT work.

BUT, if I change it to a local copy, it does.

So, I'm obliged to state that it will be a good fix to use if you are experiencing this situation.